# Is this someone trying to get inside?

Tags: php, kohana, sql-injection, kohana-orm

I am using Kohana Framework. The Framework has a error debugger (the red errors) and I have set this to send all these errors to my mail, when a customer sees this.

Today i have experienced weird actions, and some of my parameters like price, description and something else is:

```
!S!WCRTESTINPUT000002<><>%3c%3e!E!
```

> ' aNd '7'='7

I am using Kohana Query Builder for the queries.

Am i safe? What is this type of hacking, normal SQL injection? How to prevent?

Comment: looks like its done by a program looking for WoW db vulnerabilities http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/4015/t1594641-tool-produces-this-input-wcrtestinput000000/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, someone was testing if your application is vulnerable to sql injection. Good news: it passed the test. As long as you use Kohana Query Builder to build all your queries, you're safe.